# Reformulate and make clearer the Help Center page on closed questions

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, closed-questions, help-center

It is not a secret that many questions on Stack Overflow get closed, and many users (new users in particular) look for help on what it means and how to reopen them. The [Help Center page on closed questions: "What does it mean if a question is "closed"?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions) is the one that targets this audience and is intended to help.

### Common problem

While reading this page, many users encounter the link to the general Meta post: [What if I disagree with the closure of a question? How can I reopen a closed question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/helpcenter/reopen-questions). While this page correctly suggests

> the best place to ask is on **the community's meta site**

as one of the possible ways to reopen the question, it often leads to users posting on general Meta, not at Stack Overflow Meta.

### Why this might happen?

In my opinion, several factors contribute:

1. [The Stack Overflow Help Center page on closed questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions) **does not even mention** or link to [Stack Overflow Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/). Therefore, some fraction of the users might not even be aware of the Stack Overflow Meta.
2. The sheer existence of [the link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/helpcenter/reopen-questions) to general Meta. Maybe, it is more appropriate to have this information either on the same page or link [to a specific Help Center page of Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/reopen-questions), avoiding linking to an external Meta.
3. While the [page on general Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/helpcenter/reopen-questions) has a pretty specific paragraph on per-site Meta's and how to find them, maybe the wording can be improved, say, including instruction of what not to do.

Items 1,2 can be handled internally on Stack Overflow.

[This related question on general Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/355382/383809) is targeting item 3.

Can we improve this page to avoid the constant flow of such questions to general Meta?

### Reference

- [This, soon-to-be-closed and probably deleted-in-the-future question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/355379/383809) with [comment1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/355379/why-is-my-question-being-closed-as-opinion-based?noredirect=1#comment1187548_355379), [comment2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/355379/why-is-my-question-being-closed-as-opinion-based?noredirect=1#comment1187550_355379) leading me to write the story as I wrote it.
- My general feel cleaning the "Close Votes" review queue on general Meta and seeing similar questions probably daily.

Comment: For some reason, the help center page on closing questions links to Meta.SE's help page on reopening questions, rather than the [local Stack Overflow version](https://stackoverflow.com/help/reopen-questions). If that link were changed on all sites to link to the local help center copy rather than to Meta Stack Exchange, this would be much better.

Comment: @gparyani good point. Added that to item 2.

Comment: this looks worth [meta-tag:status-review]

Comment: @AntonMenshov one way to help this issue before it even gets to the metas is including examples in the post of why things are closed - so in the part where it says 'this post has been closed becuase of these reasons' - give examples.  so in the case where something is closed bc it is 'opinion-based' it would be nice to include: 'Opinion-based posts can include but not limited to: 1. best practice posts 2. opinion columns 3. .... etc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As noted in [your answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/403417/1478931), the [`/help/closed-questions`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions) page of the help center (titled "What does it mean if a question is "closed"?") has this line at the end of the article:

> For more about reopening questions, see "What if I disagree with the closure of a question? How can I reopen a closed question?"

This text links to the `/help/reopen-questions` page of the help center, which is fine. However, the problem is that this link was specifically pointing to the Meta Stack Exchange version of that help center article (https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/reopen-questions), meaning that users would be taken from SO to MSE instead.

I've fixed this help center article to use a relative link (`/help/reopen-questions`) instead. That way, this link will take SO users to the [corresponding help center article on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/reopen-questions). (I also made some other minor fixes to the article while I was at it.)

Answer (score 4):

I think that a simple change of the link on [Stack Overflow Help Center for closed questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions) might be sufficient. So, instead of the current last paragraph:

> ...
>
> For more about reopening questions, see ["What if I disagree with the closure of a question? How can I reopen a closed question?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/helpcenter/reopen-questions)

it should be:

> ...
>
> For more about reopening questions, see ["What if I disagree with the closure of a question? How can I reopen it?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/reopen-questions)

<sup>[see where the links go, it is not about the text in this suggestion]</sup>

With that, all the links on the aforementioned Help Center page link to Stack Overflow resources, and much less confusion is happening.

This particular change does not require any writing and simply corrects the existing inconsistency.